# Backbone JS - this.model.models instead of this.collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm new to Backbone JS and have been following [Christopher Coenraets Wine Cellar tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/).

It all works fine and dandy but I don't understand how he is using `this.model.models` to access a collection rather than `this.collection`. Furthermore when I try changing the code to the latter it appears that `this.collection` is undefined.

```
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: `models` is a member of a Collection object.  The name that a Collection is assigned to (`model` vs `collection`) is just like any other variable name and has no connection to the type of object contained.

Answer (score 6):

Two things lead to your dismay:

- You can inject a collection in a view however you want. The usual way is to pass a collection attribute, but here it is passed as a model in the router:

  ```
  this.wineList = new WineCollection();
  this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});
  ```
- [collection.models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) holds the raw array of models in a collection

  > **models** *collection.models*
  >   Raw access to the JavaScript array of models inside of the collection.
  >   Usually you'll want to use get, at, or the Underscore methods to
  >   access model objects, but occasionally a direct reference to the array
  >   is desired.

If you want to use `this.collection` in your view, you should modify the router to

```
this.wineList = new WineCollection();
this.wineListView = new WineListView({collection: this.wineList});
```

and you could then use it as

```
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        // Backbone proxies Underscore methods on collections
        // _.each(this.collection.models, function (wine) {

        this.collection.each(function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model: wine}).render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});
```